# How to find id of input field when getElementById does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to write a userscript javascript code in Firefox that will fill out a form. The form can be found [here](http://upickem-football.stltoday.com/profootball/framed/registration/registration.asp?contestid=3). The first input to fill appears to have id = "txtFirstName" yet when I try to find the element using **getElementById**, my console log returns **null**.

This is the code I'm using.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("txtFirstName"));
```

I eventually want to use a bunch of statements like:

```
document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value="SeanM";
```

How can I find the id of the input field so that I can assign a value to it?

Nested very deep in their code is this:

```
<input name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName" maxlength="20" value="" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code? is the ID of the element actually set to `txtFirstName`? Is that element nested inside of an `iFrame` that you don't have access to?

Comment: document.getElementById('txtFirstName') does work for me on your given example.

Comment: I am not sure this Community is there to help you write a script to Brute Force attack someone's site.

Comment: it works for me. Make sure you wait for your DOM to fully load.

Comment: You have only 1 element with current ID?

Comment: Is it nested inside of an `iFrame` element? Because if so, that element will be inaccessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't wait for my DOM to fully load. Thank you all for the help.